# Compilation of OpenCV opencv_test_photo error

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am trying to compile OpenCV 3.4.9 with MinGW53_32. When I compiled OpenCV using CMake, I found the following problems:

> [ 96%] Built target opencv_perf_objdetect
> [ 96%] Built target opencv_test_superres
> [ 97%] Built target opencv_test_stitching
> [ 98%] Built target opencv_perf_superres
> [ 98%] Built target opencv_perf_stitching
> [ 98%] Built target opencv_test_videostab
> D:\Opencv\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\photo\test\test_hdr.cpp: In
> member function 'virtual void
> opencv_test::{anonymous}::Photo_AlignMTB_regression_Test::Body()':
> D:\Opencv\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\photo\test\test_hdr.cpp:133:39:
> error: 'time' was not declared in this scope
> srand(static_cast(time(0)));
> ^
> modules\photo\CMakeFiles\opencv_test_photo.dir\build.make:165: recipe
> for target
> 'modules/photo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_photo.dir/test/test_hdr.cpp.obj'
> failed
> mingw32-make[2]: ***
> [modules/photo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_photo.dir/test/test_hdr.cpp.obj]
> Error 1                  CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2601: recipe for target
> 'modules/photo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_photo.dir/all' failed
> mingw32-make[1]: ***
> [modules/photo/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_photo.dir/all] Error 2
> Makefile:180: recipe for target 'all' failed
> mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2

I was almost successful, but this problem came up and I didn't know how to solve it.  I didn't find any information on this bug.

Answer (score 1):

MinGW 32-bit is no longer supported when building OpenCV in Windows as per here: https://answers.opencv.org/question/122696/is-it-possible-to-build-opencv-320-libraries-using-mingw-for-a-32bit-windows/.  I know you're using Windows from the paths that you have shown in your debug outputs.

However, this looks like a really simple fix.  Go into `D:\Opencv\opencv\opencv\sources\modules\photo\test\test_hdr.cpp` and place this statement where the header declarations are:

```
#include <ctime>
```

The error you see in this file is because `time` is a function that's part of the `ctime` header which is not found in the file.  I am consulting https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/photo/test/test_hdr.cpp from the official OpenCV repo.  Make sure this is included then build it again.

Comment: Oh, great! Thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome. Please let the community know that your problem is solved by accepting this answer. You can do that by clicking on the checkmark icon at the top of this answer, to the left below the up and down voting buttons. Good luck!